# f-string, multiple format specifiers

Tags: python, string-formatting

Is it possible to use multiple format specifiers in a Python [f-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions)?

For example, let's say we want to round up numbers to two decimal points and also specify a width for print.

Individually it looks like this:

```
In [1]: values = [12.1093, 13.95123]

In [2]: for v in values: print(f'{v:.2}')
1.2e+01
1.4e+01

In [3]: for v in values: print(f'{v:<10} value')
12.1093    value
13.95123   value
```

But, is it possible to combine both?

I tried:

```
for v in values: print(f'{v:.2,<10} value')
```

But I got *Invalid format specifier error*.

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dependent on the result you want, you can combine them normally such as;

```
for v in values: print(f"{v:<10.2} value")

#1.2e+01    value
#1.4e+01    value
```

However, your result does not seem like the result you're looking for.

To force the fixed notation of the `2` you need to add `f`:

```
for v in values: print(f"{v:<10.2f} value")

#12.11      value
#13.95      value
```

You can read more on format specifications [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: Just to add something else: in this case the literal value 10 is being used as `<10`, but in case you needed to store the padding value in a variable you'd need to surround it with `{` and `}` to clearly specify it's a variable. So let's say you have `padding=10`, it would look like this: `print(f"{v:<{padding}.2f} value")`.

Answer (score 15):

You want

```py
for v in values: print(f'{v:<10.2} value')
```

Detailed rules can be found in *[Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)*:

> The general form of a *standard format specifier* is:
>
> **format_spec**     ::=
> [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][grouping_option][.precision][type]

For your case, you want the [align] and [.precision].

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you need first to specify the width and then the precision. The comma is used to separate thousands, so do not use it here:

```
>>> for v in values: print(f'{v:<10.2} value')
1.2e+01    value
1.4e+01    value
```

Answer (score 2):

Python allows multiple format specifiers. The detailed  discussion of this can be read on *[PEP 3101 – Advanced String Formatting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)*.

As for your answer, the required command is

```
for v in values: print(f'{v:<10.2} value')
```